# In Kakoune, is there a way to type something over and over?

Tags: vim, kakoune

In Vim, you can go <kbd>30i=<esc></kbd> to type 30 `=` signs. (This is handy for taking notes, becaus I like to put a bunch of equals signs under different section headers.)

Is there a way to do this in Kakoune? A numerical prefix on an `i`nsert session only types the content once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some discussion of this topic [here](https://discuss.kakoune.com/t/repeating-a-character-n-times-in-insert-mode/670/14), where the most relevant comment seems to be:

> Since [#4041](https://github.com/mawww/kakoune/issues/4041), we can create overlapping selections with the `+` command and `Alt` + `+` to merge them.
>
> Example – Insert 80 asterisks:
>
> `80+i*<esc><a-+>`

I can't quite get this to work myself (it does create a line of 80 `*` characters, but I'm not able to exit whatever mode I've gotten myself into at that point), but I haven't used `kak` before, so perhaps it will be more obvious to you.

Comment: Alright, that works! BTW, the "mode" you're in is just still having 80 cursors. You can remove all but the main selection with `,` (comma).

Comment: To merge contiguous selections (after generating all those `*`) you need to press `<a-_>`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple plugin for Kakoune that does what you want:

[Insert a character n times in Insert mode](https://github.com/ftonneau/repeat-char.kak)

The good thing about it is that you can use it while writing--no need to interrupt the flow by leaving Insert mode before reentering it. It may also be more finger-friendly than the new `+` and `Alt-+` combinations.

(By the way, this plugin is mentioned in the Discussion that *larsks* refers to.)